# VBA code to add a date range to a form to refine search

Tags: ms-access, vba

I already have a form with a Combo drop down list for "Type" (this is the Antibody field records I am searching). A "SearchRecords" button starts the code.
I want to add a start and end date to the form to refine the search. I have created date text boxes for `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
My current code is below. I need help with the VB code to get the date range.

```
Private Sub SearchRecords_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Combo24.SetFocus
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAGV_Log WHERE [Type] = '" & Me.Combo24.Text & "' Order by Date DESC"
    Me.RecordSource = ""
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
End Sub
```

Comment: What purpose does the `Combo24.SetFocus` serve?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to show than describe, but I would expand your routine like this:

```
Private Sub SearchRecords_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strOp As String

    On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAGV_Log"

    strWhere = ""
    strOp = ""
    If Not IsNull(Me.Combo24.Value) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "([Type] = '" & Me.Combo24.Value & "')"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.StartDate.Value) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "([Date] >= #" & Me.StartDate.Value & "#)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.EndDate.Value) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "([Date] <= #" & Me.EndDate.Value & "#)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If

    If Len(strWhere) > 0 then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    strSQL = strSQL & " Order by [Date] DESC"

    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

This will get you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I entered this code and tested.  When I run it, I get no results and the form seems to lock up and not allow me to try again.  The fields go blank as soon as you select a drop down selection.  Not sure why??

Comment: I'm not sure about whether this is the issue, but the only thing I can see that's different from the original SQL (aside from the added `Date` `WHERE` statement) is the parentheses. Does it work without those @Don?

Comment: Also, maybe make sure that the `Combo24` has the right bound column, so that it's `.value` isn't the PK of your [Type], but rather is the name thereof.

Comment: You are right.  Your code was good. I was bound to the wrong column.  I changed that and it is working.  Thanks for your help.